# Node.JS Transferring Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

i have a few questions. I hope this isn't abstract.

I am learning the uses of the node package cluster.
My usage is as follows,
A server in a datacenter in Chicago (VPS).
A server in my home.
And future load balancing servers hopefully.

Everything I read about the package cluster, seems to be based off of the idea of having it on 1 machine.

My goal is to be able to transfer data back and forth from the node.js instances across the country. I was told i could accommodate this idea with Cluster using a stream.

This is the code snippet from node.js api example page.

```
    var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

   Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach(function(id) {
    console.log("I am running with ID : "+cluster.workers[id].process.pid);
  });

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {

      //Do further processing.
}
```

In this instance, it appears to spin up instances within the server.
Quite obviously I need something that will work with a remote server.

Can anyone offer me any advice for this?

Thank You!

Comment: I think you are talking about load balancing. Check out nginx and use that infront of your nodejs application

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking if the cluster module will spin up servers across machines. The cluster module will not do that, it only works on the machine you are working on. Load balancing across the network is a pretty complicated topic. For one, you need to figure out how you're going to transmit the data back and forth. Will you use TCP/IP? HTTP? Then you still need to set up the cluster individually on each machine. Only then, when your clients need some work to be done, they can connect to the load balancer on your remotes using a protocol of your choosing, and send/receive data. If you're doing a worker pool, using Redis to perform pub/sub is a good idea for transmitting data back and forth.

Comment: I figured that cluster wouldn't work for this issue. All i need is to be able to transfer strings back and forth from node.js instances.

Comment: That's simple then, if you have a server running at home, and another in a data center, if you know the IP of both servers, then they can easily communicate with each other over HTTP. If this is not what you're looking for, you need to clearly state the problem you're trying to solve as "transfering data back and forth" could mean just about anything.

Comment: Okay! Thank you Yuri!. I guess i should be more concise with my topic summary. Can you suggest where I should start with HTTP communicating? I'm slightly ignorant in that area.

Comment: You need to use a server framework library, something like [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), it's the most popular of all the libraries.  You will use express to create http routes in your server. Then you will need the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module in order to create HTTP requests back and forth from your servers. You'll have to look at some examples and documentations from here on forth as the rest of the implementation is quite involved, and you'll need to learn some basic concepts first.